# Linux. GDM. Обрисовка выпадающего меню по сообщению из pam модуля

Tags: linux, аутентификация, gnome

Нужно реализовать выпадающее меню которое будет брать пункты из pam модуля.
Сейчас реализована консольная версия и при возможности выбора фактора авторизации выводится такой текст.

```
Выберите фактор:
     1)Фактор 1
     2)Фактор 2
     и т.д.
Введите номер фактора:
```

Есть ли возможность интерпретировать это сообщение для графического дисплейного менеджера в виде выпадающего меню или чего угодно? Количество и список факторов может меняться. Желательно для всех, но хотя бы для GDM.

Я предположил что для DM должен существовать какой-то интерпретатор языка для динамических изменений экрана логина (что -то на подобии JS для браузеров), но ничего подобного не нашел.

Comment: а можно немного подробнее про то как «консольный» вариант реализован?

Comment: Это pam модуль. Модуль самописный. Для отображение использую pam_message. Механизм получения списка факторов я считаю не важен.

Comment: в таком случа, поидей, DM и так должен отображать этот текст и поле ввода... средствами одного pam'а сделать это в более приличном виде не получится... правда для GDM'а гугл говорит о некоем «GDM PAM ChoiceList extension», но найти какой-либо сносной документации по этому поводу у меня не получилось...

Comment: С отображением текста все нормально. Но мне бы хотелось что бы вместо текста было выпадающее меню.

Comment: мм... тогда см. выше... в самом pam'е для этого ни каких адекватных API нет... Для gdm есть это пресловутое расширение... похоже оно прошло в master, но включено ли оно по умолчанию и собирают ли в распространённых дистрибутивах — хз... информации по сабжу практически нет, максимум, что я нашёл [этот баг](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788851) и [этот пример модуля](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/blob/wip/rstrode/list-extension/pam-extensions/pam_gdm_testlist.c) +пара упоминаний в других проектах.